# check file exist with php isn't working, need help

Tags: php, file, exists

Please advise me, what wrong with my following code:

```
<a href="<?php echo $_url; ?>" title="<?php echo $_name; ?>">
<?php   
$logo2 = $_url.'/image/data/logo2.png';
$logo = $_url.'/image/data/logo.png';

if (file_exists($logo2))  { 
 echo "<img src=".$logo2." alt=\"Logo\" style=\"border: none;\" />";
 } else {  
 echo "<img src=".$logo." alt=\"Logo\" style=\"border: none;\" />";
 } ?>
</a>
```

both images of $logo2 and $logo exists in the same directory, but the code only shows $logo (logo.png)
I need pointers and thanks in advance

UPDATED:

the value of $_url is

> $this->data['_url'] =
>   $this->config->get('config_url');

and when i `<?php echo $_url;?>` that will show e.g. http://www.mysite.com

by using code at above **only show logo.png**

Comment: You're not checking if the *file* exists, you're checking if the *URL* exists.

Comment: What is the value of `$_url` ?

Comment: Hi, the value of $_url is http://www.mysite.com after echoing as i recently updated above

Comment: sorry, but that code possible show logo.png.

Comment: because first condition is wrong

Comment: OK, now this work, i apply it to a filesystem path, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file_exists`  can be used for URL wrapper.

In your case, if you really need to perform URL wrapper checking (will be very slow), make sure URL wrapper is enabled (default is enabled).

And also, your `$_url = http://www.mysite.com///image/data/logo2.png`, take note the extra slash may affecting web server rewrite.

If the file is located at the same server as your web server, you should replace the `$_url` to document_root (path to the folder).

For function wise, `file_exists` return true for directory too. You should replace that to `is_file`

Answer (score 1):

You are applying `file_exists()` to a URL which doesn't work.

You need  to apply it to a filesystem path.

Answer (score 0):

`file_exists` expects a *local path*, not a *url*.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to some answers here, file_exists can take an URL as a parameter and it will check whether it exists or doesn't. However, you're still better off using a filesystem path for file_exists instead of the URL.

Anyway, two reasons immediately come to mind:

1. Do both files have the same permissions? (I.e., logo.png might have the necessary read permissions and logo2.png might not have them)
2. Are the file names really the same as in the script? For example, everything might work fine on your development platform - a Mac or Windows which ignores letter case for filenames but not on a Linux server where the filename must be in the same case.

Answer (score -1):

Use [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)() as file_exists will return false.

```
<a href="<?php echo $_url; ?>" title="<?php echo $_name; ?>">
<?php   
$logo2 = $_url.'/image/data/logo2.png';
$logo = $_url.'/image/data/logo.png';

if (getimagesize($logo2))  { 
    echo "<img src=".$logo2." alt=\"Logo\" style=\"border: none;\" />";
 } else {  
    echo "<img src=".$logo." alt=\"Logo\" style=\"border: none;\" />";
 } ?>
</a>
```